# Group rows and get max from each group.

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

Below I have table - Company

```
  id name value year
    1  IBM   10   2011
    2  IBM   30   2012
    3  IBM   10   2012
    4  C     10   2010
```

I want to group records by *name* and from each group return only one record with maximum *id*. All results combine into the list of companies using linq where year is greater 2011. For my example output should be - "3 IBM 10 2012"

I did write something but does not working.

```
var a = from x in companies where x.year > 2011
                  group x by new {x.name, x.value, x.ID, x.year } into g
                  select new {
                                  g.Key.name,
                                  g.Key.value,
                                  g.Max(a=>a.ID),
                                  g.Key.value
                              };
 return a.ToList();
```

Comment: You mean you want it to return "3 IBM 10 2012", yes?

Comment: Do you want to group by x.ID ?

Comment: yes i meant return "3 IBM 10 2012"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var a = from x in companies
                where x.Year > 2011
                group x by new { x.Name } into g
                from x1 in companies
                where x1.ID == (from x2 in g select x2.ID).Max()
                select x1;
```

Or something more efficient:

```
var a = from x in companies
                    where x.Year > 2011
                    group x by new { x.Name } into g
                    join x2 in companies on (from x3 in g select x3.ID).Max() equals x2.ID
                    select x2;
```

Comment: after using this when I try return a.ToList(); at the end of function it throws error Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<company>'

Answer (score 0):

Don't include the ID in your grouping. In fact, if you just want them grouped by company name, don't include any of those other properties either:

```
// set up for testing
var companies =
    from c in new[]{"1,IBM,10,2011", "2,IBM,30,2012", "3,IBM,10,2012", "4,C,10,2010"}
    let cp = c.Split(',')
    select new {id=int.Parse(cp[0]), name=cp[1], value=int.Parse(cp[2]), year=int.Parse(cp[3])};

// query
var q = from x in companies where x.year > 2011
        group x by x.name into g
        let top = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).FirstOrDefault()
        select new {
                        top.name,
                        top.value,
                        top.id,
                        top.year
                    };
```

Comment: If i dont group by ID, I can't do   g.Max(a=>a.ID) but ID will be inaccessible.

Comment: sorry I tried that way but it throws error - Error 3 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @user570715: There were various other problems with your original code. I just posted an update which definitely works. (I tested it in LINQPad)